# Proving Kernelshap is trustful

Tags: shap

Am working on shap implementation and am trying to prove that kernelshap is trustful , the main concern is that since kernelshap is fitting a linear model to determine shap values  there will be some sort of uncertainty since it's an approximation .
I tried to look for some metrics but what we have in the library https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/benchmark/metrics.py are metrics dedicated for the existing methods (benchmark) . I tried comparing shap values of treexplainer since it's an exact calculation for the same data and I assumed at least to find that most important features are the same when calculating with kernelshap but am not getting comparable results .

these are shap values for Boston housing dataset with treexplainer (model : XGBRegressor) :
[image: shap values for Boston housing dataset with treexplainer (model : XGBRegressor)]

These are shap values for Boston housing dataset with Kernelshap (model : SVR) :
[image: shap values for Boston housing dataset with Kernelshap (model : SVR)]

Comment: You're comparing 2 different models that are not comparable.

Comment: @Sergey Bushmanov  I  was just trying to prove kernel shap values are exact and I thought that when dealing with the same dataset with two different algorithms the most important features at least the top ones will be the same.
I know that the two models are approaching the data in two different ways but do you have any idea how to prove that kernel shap is trustful ??

Comment: I suggest several things: (1) revisit couple of different algos like linear regression and decision trees or SVM and see how they are constructed; (2) find a paper on SHAP and see if that answers your question